# Method Not Allowed http exception using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

What is causing this exception? What is the meaning of `MethodNotAllowedException`? I am using Laravel 5.2.

HTML and input fields:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label">Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" data-validate="required" placeholder="Enter Name" />
                    </div>

<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label">Detail</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="detail" id="detail" placeholder="Enter Detail"></textarea> 
                    </div>
<input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <div class="form-group col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" onclick="postdata();" id="post" class="btn btn-success">Submit Now</button>

                    </div>
```

AJAX function:

```
function postdata(){

   var name=$('#name').val();
   var detail=$('#detail').val(); 
   var token=$('#_token').val();
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{url("/posts")}}',
                    data: "name="+ name + "&detail="+ detail+"&_token="+ token ,
                    success: function(data){ 

                    }  });
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');
```

Error after clicking button:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
     in RouteCollection.php line 219
    at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
    at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
    at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
    at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
```

Comment: For your console can you confirm that the request is definitely going to the right endpoint? Also, if the `Route` inside any route groups?

Comment: Is that ajax function inside a php file or js file? Also, open your console and check if the call is going to this url or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the routes.php file, what method you are using for this request, it should be something like:
`Route::post('/posts', 'AnyController@method');`

Comment: i have only two routes in routes file  Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');  
Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');

Comment: i want to submit data by post method Route::post('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');  when i will change post to get method Route::get('/posts', 'Cdesigination@index');  working is fine then i will change get to post then show error and my route have post method and ajax type is also  'POST' and when route  get method and ajax type is also  'Get' then better working can tell me how to post data by both route and ajax type post

Comment: when i use the get method in route and ajax type working better as soon as i will change get to post type in route and ajax type  then show error Method Not Allowed http exception

Comment: ajax function use  in view file i'm using blade engine template  ajax call is going to   this url  http://localhost/school/posts